# Match A to B, correct match disappear, and timer and error count

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would appreciate some guidance with this matching activity. I illustrate with the basic `html` and `css` code below - this is the format that I want, meaning, I want the contents (**words/numbers**) of the boxes to be changeable in the `HTML` section, I just need help with the `javascript`.

Aim: to match A to B, so for example, when user clicks on `"aaaaaaaa"` and `"11111111"` then the match is correct and both boxes disappears. However if for example the user clicks on `"aaaaaaaa"` and `"33333333"` then it is recorded and counted as an error which is then displayed on the page.

Also, how to add a timer from the moment the page is loaded till all the matches are made and the activity is finished ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

#wordBx
{
width:168px;
height:168px;
border:1px grey solid;
text-align:center;
padding:1px;
float:left;
}

.word
{
width:165px;
height:40px;
border:1px grey solid;
}

#numBox
{
width:50%;
height:400px;
border:1px blue solid;
text-align:center;
margin:1px;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
 }

.numb
{
width:180px;
height:70px;
border:1px blue solid;
margin:2px;
float:left;
font-size:11pt;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wordBx">
<div class="word">aaaaaaaa</div >
<div class"word">bbbbbbbb</div >
<div class="word">cccccccc</div >
<div class="word">dddddddd</div >
</div>

<div id="numBox">
<div class="numb">11111111</div >
<div class="numb">22222222</div >
<div class="numb">33333333</div >
<div class="numb">44444444</div >
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple HTML elements with the same ID, you should use classes instead, `<div class="word">xxxxxxxx</div>`

Comment: add tags and some formatting issue resolved

Comment: @Sayna you should add a function click to all your elements. If it's clicked save it. If the save is different from the old save, do your thing show them if needed else hide them.

Comment: @ChrisWissmach, thanks! Didn't know - newbie here, might be obvious! :)

Comment: @Pleasure, thanks for your reply, basically I need JavaScript to do like this in this link: http://jeux.lulu.pagesperso-orange.fr/html/anglais/assoMemo/aPoussi1.htm.

Comment: @Pleasure, and to include a counter which counts and displays the number of errors made - any ideas how to do this anyone?

Comment: What defines that `1111111` is the "match" for `aaaaaaa`?  How is this known?

Comment: @cale_b, this is part of what I need help to figure out how to do... any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sayna if you could tell me if that's what you want or not.

Comment: @Pleasure, sorry I was trying to reply below under your answer but I couldn't tag you... anyway, I tried your answer briefly and it didn't work. I've edited my initial post now to 'class' as suggested. Did you take a look at the link I posted as an example of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sanya You can't tag me because it's my answer. Yea I did and what I wrote is exactly that. Sec

Comment: @Pleasure, ok, thanks again, I think it's because I made the 'class' mistake that its not working... would you mind helping me out on that as Ive confused myself!

Comment: @Sayna try it again, should work. That was a mistake by me.

Comment: @Pleasure, I tried it and it works except, if I click on "aaaaaaaa" twice it disappears, this is not to happen, I want only when "aaaaaaaa" AND "11111111" are clicked that the match is accepted and so they disappear otherwise they remain until they are BOTH clicked - I hope this is not confusing . Also, I would like the number of errors to be counted... help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var words = document.querySelectorAll('.word');
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var selectedWordIndex;
var selectedNumberIndex;
var timerInstance;

// Validate game settings
if (words.length !== numbers.length) {
    return console.error('Words list size should be same as numbers list');
}

// Register click event handlers on all words and numbers
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
  words[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        selectedWordIndex = this.dataset.index;
    checkMatching();
    });  
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
    numbers[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        selectedNumberIndex = this.dataset.index;
        checkMatching();
    });
}

function checkMatching() {
    // When user selection matches
    if (selectedWordIndex === selectedNumberIndex) {
    // Remove pair
    var word = document.querySelector('.word[data-index="' + selectedWordIndex + '"]')
    var number = document.querySelector('.number[data-index="' + selectedNumberIndex + '"]')
    word.parentNode.removeChild(word);
    number.parentNode.removeChild(number);

    // Reset selection
    selectedWordIndex = null;
    selectedNumberIndex = null;

    // Check if game is ended
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.word').length === 0) {
      // Remove blocks and stop the timer
        var words = document.querySelector('.words');
        var numbers = document.querySelector('.numbers');
        words.parentNode.removeChild(words);
        numbers.parentNode.removeChild(numbers);
        clearInterval(timerInstance);
    }
  } else if (selectedWordIndex && selectedNumberIndex) {
    // Register an error while selection does not match
    var errorCounter = document.querySelector('.errors .counter');
    errorCounter.innerHTML = parseInt(errorCounter.innerHTML, 10) + 1;
  }
}

function startTimer() {
    var display = document.querySelector('.time');
    var timer = 0, minutes, seconds;
    timerInstance = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        timer++;
    }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

I have created JSFiddle with all of stuff you needed

[JSFiddle (UPDATED)](https://jsfiddle.net/ogo96ks6/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
HTML 

<div id="wordBx">
<div id="word1" onclick="save(word1)" class='class1'>aaaaaaaa</div >
<div id="word2" onclick="save(word2)" class='class2'>bbbbbbbb</div >
<div id="word3" onclick="save(word3)" class='class3'>cccccccc</div >
<div id="word4" onclick="save(word4)" class='class4'>dddddddd</div >
</div>

<div id="numBox">
<div id="numb1" onclick="save(numb1)" class='class1'>11111111</div >
<div id="numb2" onclick="save(numb2)" class='class2'>22222222</div >
<div id="numb3" onclick="save(numb3)" class='class3'>33333333</div >
<div id="numb4" onclick="save(numb4)" class='class4'>44444444</div >
</div>
```

elements shouldn't have the same id.

And

```
JAVASCRIPT :


var old = undefined;
var number = 0;
function save(t) {
    document.getElementById(t);
    if(old != undefined && t.className == old.className && old != t) {
        t.style.display = "none";
        old.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
    number = number +1;
    if ( number / 2 == 1 && number != 0) {      
        document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Try number " + parseInt(number/2);
        }

    }
        old = t;
}
```

For the event to trigger when the game should end use :

```
setTimeout(myFunction, timeInMSeconds)
```

And for the timer you can use it again.

Comment: This is a very good effort, however, it's doing some things that I don't want.

Basically, what I am wanting to achieve is like a memory game except the cards are NOT identical and do not turn or flip over... when a match is made, the 2 matching cards disappear, and each error is counted, the game is played until the board is cleared.

Comment: Yea I am garbage at JS ! check my new version. Haven't had much time to test the number, try to fix it by yourself, have to go. Good luck ! Hopefully I helped you !